# AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize_azure'

Tags: python

I'm trying to make Uberi recognition speech (python) work, but `recognize_azure` gives me errors.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone()

AZURE_SPEECH_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

with m as source: r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

print("Say something!")
with m as source: audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("Microsoft Azure Speech thinks you said " + r.recognize_azure(audio, key=AZURE_SPEECH_KEY))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Microsoft Azure Speech could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Microsoft Azure Speech service; {0}".format(e))
```

And this is the result:

> AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize_azure'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an out-of-date version of the `speech_recognition` package. `recognize_azure` is not provided by it yet.

In particular the package currently listed on pypi.org is too old. You may need to install it from the source code, see github link below.

As far as I can tell there hasn't been any release since the version pypi is listing, so your only chance seems to be to install from the git master.

See https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/385

Comment: Thank you very much, this totally satisfies my question. Indeed, the module install it from pypi and it seems that it was not fully updated. Once installed from git, it was fixed. Thanks again. +1